# Does the Sentinel feat actually “lock down” enemies like this?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, feats

Say I'm a Battle Master using a 2-handed weapon, and I have Riposte, Trip Attack, and the Sentinel feat, and there's a friendly rogue beside me.

If a 5-feet creature hit me, and misses, I can Riposte, then apply the rule 1 of Sentinel to make its movement 0 for that round. Then when my turn comes I can use Trip Attack to make it go prone. Does this mean that when its turn comes, the enemy can't stand up because it has no movement?

Also, if it hits the rogue, could I use Sentinel rule 3 and then apply Trip Attack to make the creature prone and have 0 speed? Is that legit/viable?

I'm confused!

Comment: For clarification, when you say 5-feet creature, do you mean a medium or small sized creature?

Answer (score 26):

## No. No. Mostly no.

One at a time:

---

### Can I apply Sentinel rule 1 to a Battlemaster's Riposte?

**No.** You can't because the Riposte isn't an opportunity attack. Sentinel rule 1 only works on opportunity attacks.

> **Riposte**
>
> When a creature misses you with a melee attack, you can use your reaction and expend one superiority die **to make a melee weapon attack** against the creature. If you hit, you add the superiority die to the attack's damage roll.

Your confusion on this point is understandable. Ripostes and Opportunity attacks are both (usually) melee weapon attacks that use your reaction. But that doesn't mean that every reaction attack is an opportunity attack.

> **Sentinel** (rule 1)
>
> When you hit a creature with an opportunity attack, the creature’s speed becomes 0 for the rest of the turn.

Sentinel strict applies to opportunity attacks, not Ripostes, Ready Actions, or other attacks that you might use your reaction for.

> **Opportunity attack**
>
> You can make an opportunity attack when a hostile creature that you can see moves out of your reach. To make the opportunity attack, you use your reaction to make one melee attack against the provoking creature.

Opportunity attacks **only** occur if a creature leaves your reach (or another says otherwise).

---

### If I debuff a creature's speed with Sentinel and trip it, will it be stuck on its next round?

**No.** The movement debuff lasts for the rest of the *turn*, not the *round* (see quote above). A turn is one creature's chance to act. So if a monster moves out of reach during its turn, your opportunity attack *also* takes place during its turn. As soon as the next creature starts acting, its speed will no longer be 0.

---

### Could I use Sentinel rule 3 and then apply Trip Attack to make the creature prone and have 0 speed?

**Mostly no.** Again, the attack that Sentinel provides you is not an opportunity attack.

> **Sentinel** (rule 3)
>
> When a creature within 5 feet of you makes an attack against a target other than you (and that target doesn’t have this feat), you can use your reaction to make a melee weapon attack against the attacking creature.

If instead of hitting the rogue, the monster moved out of your reach, then it *would* be an opportunity attack, and you would be able to trip and debuff their speed. So make sure the rogue knows not to stand right next to you.

---

### Bonus question: Can I use Trip Attack with Sentinel rule 3?

**Yes.** The only requirement for Trip attack is that you hit with a weapon attack (it doesn't even need to be melee). You can use this with the Attack action, bonus action attacks like Two-weapon fighting, Opportunity Attacks, Sentinel rule 3 attacks or pretty much anything else as long as its a weapon attack.

> **Trip attack**
>
> When you hit a creature with a weapon attack, you can expend one superiority die to attempt to knock the target down...

Different maneuvers have different requirements, so be sure to read each one carefully (for example, sweeping attack requires a *melee* weapon attack). And remember, only 1 maneuver per attack.

Comment: Ok i get it, only one doubt remaining, rule 3 on Sentinel doesnt give me an aoO, but it gives me an attack, and Trip attack doesnt require and aoO (atleast it doesnt state so). So why cant i use Sentinel (rule 3) and add Trip attack or Precision attack for example? Thanks again!!

Comment: You can add maneuvers to your Sentinel rule 3 attack. I'll edit the answer to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Sentinel applies only to attacks of opportunity. Not all attacks made using your reaction are AoO, only those that are explicitly stated to be. Neither Ripost, nor Sentinel give you an AoO. (Contrast Polearm Master, which does.)

Thus in the scenarios you describe, the enemy's movement will not be reduced.

Comment: But everything i waid is under attack of opportunity... or not?

1- Hitting him with Riposte is an attack of opportunity, right?

2- Hitting him with sentinel 3rd rule is an attack of opportunity, right?

Comment: It doesn't matter because Riposte doesn't grant an AoO, but it might be worth pointing out that this also wouldn't work because Sentinel only stops movement for the turn not the round.

Comment: @LaioZatt Just because an attack of opportunity uses your reaction to grant you a melee attack doesn't mean that everything that uses your reaction to grant you a melee attack is an attack of opportunity.

Comment: @LaioZatt If you have a new question, please post it by clicking the Ask Question button. This site isn't a discussion forum and its features do not support having a conversation or multiple questions inside the comments. (For more about how the site works, take the [tour] or browse the [help].)